# Convert the PropTypes compatible to TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-proptypes

What I'm trying to do is to pass a props and be compatible with both PropTypes and TypeScript.

I have this Props `inputGroupAddon`:

```
      <TextField
        value={value}
        inputGroupAddon={{
          prepend: {
            icon: 'First',
            class: ''
          },
          append: {
            icon: 'Last',
            class: ''
          }
        }}
      />
```

Which should be compatible to propTypes:

```
TextField.propTypes = {
  inputGroupAddon: PropTypes.objectOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      icon: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.element]),
      class: PropTypes.string
    })
  )
}
```

How can I make this compatible with TypeScript?

```
type inputGroup = {
  icon: Element | string
  class: string
}

export type TextFieldType = {
  value: string | any
  inputGroupAddon: inputGroup | null
}
```

Comment: Aren't your proptypes missing a level? I would expect to see `prepend` and `append` inside that first `objectOf`.

Comment: How should the missing level be added? sorry im new to proptypes

Comment: This resource answers that question better than I could. https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your props assignment it looks like this might work:

```js
type inputGroup = {
  icon: Element | string
  class: string
}

type InputGroupAddon = {
  prepend?: inputGroup
  append?: inputGroup
}

export type TextFieldType = {
  value: string | any
  inputGroupAddon: InputGroupAddon
}
```

Comment: What if the value of icon is:  `const iconD = () => <span class='material-icons'>account_circle</span>` `append: {icon: iconD}` what should be the typescript of the icon? `string | ReactNode`?