# Function type in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

With regards to my previous question:

[Convert the PropTypes compatible to TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67267116/convert-the-proptypes-compatible-to-typescript/67267432#67267432)

if I have this function to pass:

```
const iconD = () => <span class='material-icons'>account_circle</span>
```

And, `iconD` will be pass to `<TextField/>`

```
 <TextField
        value={value}
        inputGroupAddon={{
          prepend: {
            icon: iconD
          }
        }}
      />
```

What TypeScript should the `icon` have?

I already tried:

```
type inputGroup = {
  icon: ReactElement | string
  class: string
}
```

I'm still having this error:

[image]

Comment: Isn't the TextField `value` a `string`?

Comment: My question is the `icon`, not the `value`

Comment: If below answers are useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If any answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it (once the system allows that). That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Your icon should be an `ReactElement`, not a function that returns an `ReactElement`.

Replace

```
const iconD = () => <span class='material-icons'>account_circle</span>
```

With

```
const iconD = <span class='material-icons'>account_circle</span>
```

If you do want to pass a function, update your typings:

```
type inputGroup = {
  icon: (() => ReactElement) | string
  class: string
}
```

Comment: But if the user insists to the pass a function? What type should be using?
`const iconD = () => <span class='material-icons'>account_circle</span>`

Comment: @Ayaka `() => ReactElement` ?

Comment: I already tried it. but there's an error message ^ See the attached error message

Comment: @Ayaka Are you sure you tried that? Your typing shows `ReactElement | string` not `() => ReactElement`

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ReactNode` which is defined as:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

and `iconD` as:

```
const iconD = <span className="material-icons">account_circle</span>
```

So the typings become:

```
type inputGroup = {
  icon: ReactNode
  className: string
}
```

Comment: What if, it must use a ```= () =>``` what should be type of this?

Comment: `icon: () => ReactNode`

Comment: Also, it depends on what values `iconD` can take. Feel free to tell me all the possible values you want to assign to `iconD`. E.g. `const iconD = () => <span>...</span>`,  `const iconD = () => null`,  `const iconD = () => "foo"` etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
type inputGroup = {
  icon: () => JSX.Element
  class: string
}
```